# ExtJS 3.0.0: GridPanel in a Window with an ArrayStore not rendering any data

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, extjs3, gridpanel

I'm trying to put a GridPanel powered by an ArrayStore in a Window, but no matter what I do, it just looks like this with no data rows inside:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
           var ticketsStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore
            (
                {
                    autoDestroy: false,
                    remoteSort: false,
                    data: result,
                    fields:
                    [
                        { name: 'articleId', type: 'int' },
                        { name: 'heatTicketRef', type: 'string' },
                        { name: 'username', type: 'string' },
                        { name: 'dateLinked', type: 'date' }
                    ]
                }
         );

        var ticketsGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            store: ticketsStore,
            id: this.id + 'ticketsGrid',
            viewConfig: {
                emptyText: 'No data'
            },
            autoShow: true,
            idProperty: 'heatTicketRef',
            columns: [
                { id: 'heatTicketRef', header:"Ticket ID", width: 100, dataIndex: 'heatTicketRef', sortable: false },
                { header: "User", width: 100, dataIndex: 'username', sortable: false },
                { header: "Date Linked", width: 100, dataIndex: 'dateLinked', xtype: 'datecolumn', format: 'j M Y h:ia', sortable: false }
            ]
        });
        var window = new Ext.Window
          (
            {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                id: this.id + 'linkedHeatTickets',
                closable: true,
                modal: true,
                autoHeight: true,
                width: 500,
                title:'Linked Heat Tickets',
                resizable: false,
                listeners:
                {
                    close: function () { // do something }
                },
                items:
                {
                    style: 'padding:5px;',
                    items: ticketsGrid
                },
                buttons:
                {
                    text: 'Close',
                    handler: function () {
                        window.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        window.show();
```

When I debug, I can see that my "result" object is healthy and the ArrayStore is of the right length:
[image]

But the GridPanel doesn't like the data because it's not in its items (although it's in the store) array:

[image]

What little thing have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: set minheight to grid and try

Comment: I tried minHeight, unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: try fiddle i can help you

Comment: I just tried but for some reason the ExtJS loade dby Fiddlr doesn't have the ArrayStore in it... http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E4KqfMI17p

Comment: remove the types and try

Comment: Sorry, I've never used jsfiddle with anyone before.. it doesn't have store...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87006/discussion-between-lilalfyalien-and-raghavendra).

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm an idiot... I used an ArrayStore instead of a JsonStore!